# PhoneGap Doesn't see assets/www/index.html

Tags: cordova, dreamweaver

I'm using the DreamWeaver CS6 PhoneGap extension to build an app.

It works fine if I put the index in the base of the site e.g.

```
Main Folder
  -index.html
```

But When I use an assets/www file structure like I have seen many times around the web it doesn't work. It just generates a default index.html in the Main Folder. Current file structure is as follows...

```
Main Folder
  -assets
    -www
      -index.html
  -res
  -src
```

When I click on Rebuild Application with the updated structure I get the following message.

[image]

[Zipped Project Files](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32351813/app.zip)

---

Edit: FOR ANYONE HAVING PROBLEMS WITH DW CS6. I HAD MANY PROBLEMS CAUSED BY THE FILE NOT BEING UPDATED WHEN REBUILD. I HAD TO DELETE THE PROJECT ON PHONEGAP.COM RESTART DW AND REBUILD NEW.

Comment: I don't understand the problem: once you have this structure, edit the index.html, and replace the contents with your code?

Comment: The problem is that my compiled phonegap program looks for MainFolder/index.html instead of MainFolder/assets/www/index.html.

Comment: I've attached the project files for anyone willing to download and try building it to see what I mean.

Comment: Looks like a Blackberry project? Anyway the structure is wrong: res and src should be outside assets, on the same level.

Comment: I've updated the structure but still same. Why do you say BlackBerry? I have been doing mostly BlackBerry lately but this one is meant for Android.

Comment: The ProjectSettings file says "ios":null and "android":null but blackberry has all the details filled out. I assumed it was a BB project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tried to do anything Phonegap-related in DW, and I do everything in the Terminal and BBEdit, so my mileage and yours may vary... But. The image below is the correct structure for an Android/Phonegap app. (Ignore `bin`: that and `gen` are generated by ant while building the app.) Have you tried going the command line, at least for building? There's [a nice little tutorial](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/30864168/phonegap-android-terminal-quickstart).

[image: Android Folder structure]

Comment: I think moving the res and src was the right fix, but it seems there are some problems with the project not updating properly. I had to delete it off phonegap restart DreamWeaver(a few times) and then it suddenly started working right.

Comment: Cool. I still recommend you try out the command line bit for creating an app -- and edit your html in DW separately. I might be a control freak, but I prefer to know what's happening, and control the work flow.